# how to display contens of an array depending on the url?

Tags: php, arrays

I've made a 'calss map' with nested arrays and I have to make a function that takes the url and serves the contents of an array within an array depending on the url adress.

here is my class map in one file:

```
class mapa_klas {  
    public $tablica_klas = array(  
        'kontroler' => array('kontroler' => 'kontroler_glowny.php', 'uzytkownik' => 'uzytkownik.php'),   
        'o_mnie' => array('kontroler' => 'o_mnie.php', 'szablon' => 'o_mnie.tpl'),   
        'kontakt' => array('kontroler' => 'kontakt.php', 'szablon' => 'kontakt.tpl'),  
        'index' => array('kontroler' => 'index.php'),  
    );  
    public function pobierzKlase() {  
        print_r($tablica_klas['o_mnie']);  
    }  
}
```

and here i'm trying to get the contents of the nested array:

```
function pobierzUri() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $klasa = new mapa_klas();
    $klasa - > pobierzKlase($uri);
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to use more understandable (not Polish) variable names for an example.

Comment: how does your uri look like. give an example please.

Comment: URI's are just like the values in the arrays: o_mnie.php, kontakt.php and so on.

Sorry for the polsih thingies, next time i'll make it more readeble :)

Comment: try echoing / var_dumping() the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable and see if it really is correct. If not you will need to parse it (see helle's answer below)

Comment: i echoed it and its correct. i also made the changes you told me below with the right arguments and it now works :)

thanks a lot guys! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function seems to be missing the argument.

```
public function pobierzKlase($uri) {  
   print_r($tablica_klas[$uri]);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess part of the URL shell be the key of your array?

so `kontroler, o_mnie, kontakt, index` are the keys.

```
$key = parse_the_uri_to_get_the_desired_part($uri);

public function pobierzKlase($key) {  
   print_r($tablica_klas[$key]);  
}

// todo: rename the function ;)
    function parse_the_uri_to_get_the_desired_part($uri){
        //... do what you have to do to extract the desired word
    }
```

I also recommand this link: http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php for url-parsing